# How can I remove YouTube's uploader image overlay?

Tags: youtube

I have the latest version of the YouTube app for Android (v5.1.10). At some point, the app began overlaying the uploader's user image in the upper-right-hand corner of the video. I can't click on it (it acts as if I clicked anywhere else on the video) and I can't remove it.

It never moves (unless I switch to/from full screen) or goes away, and sometimes blocks important portions of the video. Is there any way to turn this annoying non-feature off?

Answer (score 2):

What you are talking about is called [InVideo Programming](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2790636?hl=en). As a viewer, I don't think there's any way to remove this through the YouTube app. The content creator has to disable this themselves.

**Related topics:**

- [How to remove InVideo Programming from a single video?](http://www.reddit.com/r/letsplay/comments/1agndt/how_to_remove_invideo_programming_from_a_single/)